# how to repackage javax.sound using ANT?

Tags: android, ant

I want to use **javax.sound** in my app because am using *'recognito lib'* to define user voice print so I go for that [link](https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages) to repackage the sound lib to my package to solve the problem of dalvik machine error but it doesn't work it give me that error : '**the following error occured when try to executing that line build.xml 1515 '**

Comment: This package in not part of android.  If you want to make your own version you must customize the build flags to remove the ordinary prohibition on placing any code in the javax.* namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response . so how i have to do it .sorry i'm just new in using Ant